# Are there organisms that "branch more" near the leaf?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, trees

(I'm a computer scientist)

Tree branching is a [fractal patterns in nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterns_in_nature#Trees,_fractals). I know stems typically branch in two at each level (self-similarity). I guess there are plants or other organisms that branch in 3 at each level (still self-similar).

But are there organisms where the stem first branches in 2, then at the next level branches in 3 or more? And maybe at the next (maybe the last) level branches even more, say in 7? It doesn't need to be the stem of a plant, it could be any part of any organism (fungi,...), e.g. the "flower part" of a plant, or a micro-organism.

I'm looking for places where *just* the branching factor changes, but otherwise little else. What I'm not looking for "branch by 2, branch by 2, branch by 2, and then the very final step is one level of fascicle where branching is 5". I would be fine it's "branch by 2, branch by 3, then fascicle where branching is >3".

I'm trying to find if there is something in nature (e.g. organism, geological, or physical structure) that follows this pattern found in a computer science algorithm, [RecSplit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06416), which I co-authored.

Like the following: it first branches in 3, and then branches in 8. The actual numbers don't matter to me, it might as well be branch in 2, then in 3, then in 5, or so.

[image: Branch in 3, then branch in 8]

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stackexchange! Could you directly link a picture of the branching you describe? I think i found it in the linked paper, but it'd be easier if you can directly link it. Additionally your questions title starts with tree's but the question focuses more on all plants - and I don't think tree's will show the pattern you are looking for so this might mislead people a bit (other plants or maybe fungi might?, not really my area of expertise).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added a picture, and changed the title... I'm not sure what labels would be best. Feel free to edit my question!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascicle_(botany)

Comment: Thanks @John for the link! Do you consider this an answer to the question, or is it just the correct term for my awkward / clumsy description "flower part of a plant"?

Comment: @ThomasMueller I don't know enough about plant development to turn it into a full answer, but I know what you were asking existed so I want to leave the link.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I'm afraid the fascicle is only one level of branching... Sure you could say the plan is branching before that, say branching factor 2, and then the fascicle branching factor is 5... but I'm looking for two levels of branching of the same type, and one is wider...

Comment: Can you add some information about why you are interested in such an example? Branching in most plants completely is different from what is seem in your example or in phylogenetic trees. In [vascular plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vascular_plant) branching is typically from lateral buds rather than splitting of the growing tip so your question as currently formulated doesn't apply to most plants. In most plants these lateral buds are associated with the axils of leaves and thus the branching pattern primarily depends on the [phyllotaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllotaxis). ...

Comment: However, not all lateral buds grow out to form branches, so the observed branches will be a subset of those potential branches. Finally, while some plants produce leaves (and buds for branches) in whorls (all initiated at the same time and position along a stem) many produce leaves (buds) one at a time. Depending on your goal for this, I think your question may need to be rewritten to do one of the following: 1) focus on the minority of plants that show dichotomous, trichotomous, or polytomous branching, 2) allow for branching in whorls, or 3) deal with leaves/buds rather than actual branches.

Comment: Note that there may also be fungal hyphae that show "chotomous" branching. However, while I know little about that subject it seems that lateral branching is also the predominant form in that kingdom.

Comment: It looks like Penicillin might be what I'm looking for: G in https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conidiophore-branching-patterns-observed-in-Penicillium-A-Conidiophores-with-solitary_fig2_266395536 -

Comment: @tyersome Thanks a lot! If you want to write an answer (link in my comment) I can give credit to you. (I will still create a bounty tomorrow, maybe there are better examples.)

Comment: If you're satisfied by "any organism", how about humans?  The single bone of your upper arm/leg branches into two bones in the lower limb, then into five finger/toe bones.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that your question is very clear to me, but perhaps something of interest to you would be a common type of [inflorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflorescence) called an [umbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbel). specifically, a [**compound umbel** with associated umbellets](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/images/umbell2.gif).

Compound Umbel:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Educational Technology Clearinghouse](https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/5200/5260/compound-umbel_1.htm)</sup>

Some examples can be found [here](https://uni.edu/~andersow/umbels.html)

Again, since your post is not clear to me, I'll also include images of other complex inflorescences:

[image]

<sup>Source: [texaswildbuds.com](http://www.texaswildbuds.com/_Media/inflorescence_types2_med.jpeg)   [the [**compound cyme**](http://cronklab.wikidot.com/types-of-inflorescences) might be of interest to you]</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, this is interesting, however it looks like the number of branches are the same on each level (8 for Compound Umbel). I'm looking for something that branches lesscloser to the root (e.g. branch by 2), and branches more near the "top". Chervil does look OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

One case seems to be [Chervil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chervil).

Another case [Penicillin, specially figure G](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conidiophore-branching-patterns-observed-in-Penicillium-A-Conidiophores-with-solitary_fig2_266395536).

Comment: Technically Penicillin is a fungus not a plant - though I'm not sure if OP cares about the distinction for his question.

Comment: I'm the OP :-) Organism is fine. Actually, a geological structure or even physical would be fine as well - anything in nature.